# How to throw a specific exception when property not set on dynamic object

Tags: c#

I want to build up a dynamic object based on key/value pairs read in a config file, the key should become the property name and the value, the value assigned to the property.

But if the receiver of the dynamic object I pass back calls a property which doesn't exist, I want it to throw a custom exception of mine.

is it possible to override the default behaviour of dynamic to throw a custom exception if a property called is not set?

Comment: Have you looked at [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider?view=netframework-4.8)? Also please share us your code

Comment: Why would you use dynamic object for that? Isn't a dictionary a better structure to hold these type of values? Receiver could (should) check if value of interest is in the list of keys and throw exception if it is not (or do something else, more appropriate depending on your logic). Dictionary is dynamic in its nature and can have whatever you want in configuration. If configuration will contain limited and upfront known keys consider creating an object that will represent it.